# Alternatives to AudioContext.createJavaScriptNode

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I am looking a way to generate and play WAVE forms using javascript from browser. The method explained here: http://js.do/blog/sound-waves-with-javascript/, is pretty cool, but involves generating an audio file (via data URI) and doesn't suit for my current needs.

I am testing now the AudioContext API (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API/Using_Web_Audio_API), is great too but I can't find a way to generate WAV sample data from javascript, there is a JavascriptNode (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext.createJavaScriptNode) but it reports deprecated and the docs recommends to not rely on it. What is the alternative ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scriptNode = audioContext.createScriptProcessor(2048, 1, 1);